Typeguards: Generics and inheritance
We are right now discussing about TypeGuards and cannot make out when and how they are required. This is especially true when using Generics. Right now we have the following implementation
interface PropStringType extends PropBaseType{...}
interface PropNumberType extends PropBaseType{...}

class PropertyBaseComp<T>{
  config:PropBaseType
  ...
  abstract getValidators():ValidatorsFn[]
  ...
}

For usage we can use a concrete class with specified type - e.g. either 'string' or 'number'. This would for the string usage look like
class PropertyStringComponent extends PropertyBaseComp<string>{
...
  override getValidators():ValidatorsFn[] {
     ....
     const confCast=config as PropStringType; // <======
     ...
  }
}

Now the question is:
Do I need to run a check to if config is really of type PropStringType or can I trust that the Generic type string is already enough? Since I know how to configure it and how I use it.
I'm not really clear about the purpose of Typeguards and if (and how) they should be applied here.
Or does there a more "conform" solution exists which would "grant" me the "proper" types?
